# apply user-defined function on polygon to iteratively draw circles from a specific dataset in R

Tags: r

I seem to have a problem on applying a new function to a specific dataset.

I have defined a function "circle" which takes the x-coordinate x and y-coordinate y of the centre as well as the radius r as arguments and draws a polygon with vertices at    (x + r  sin(ti); y + r  cos(ti)), where ti is sequence of length 100 going from 0 to 2. Additional arguments provided to circle are passed on to polygon.

The function looks like this:

```
circle<-function(x,y,r,...) {       
ti<-seq(0,(2*pi),length.out = 100)           
polygon(x + r *sin(ti),y+r*cos(ti),...)
}
```

I have then modified the function so that it also works if x, y and r are vectors of length > 1.

It looks like this:

```
circle<-function(x,y,r,...) {
ti<-seq(0,(2*pi),length.out = 100)
data.fun<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,r))
for (i in 1:nrow(data.fun)) {
polygon(x[i] + r[i] *sin(ti),y[i]+r[i]*cos(ti),...)
  }

}
```

So when I use:

```
plot(c(-3,3), c(-3,3), type="n")
circle(c(0,2), c(0,0), c(1, 0.5))
```

it draws a circle with a smaller circle to its right.

However, when I try to apply the function to a given dataset and use column names for x,y, and r, it doesn't work.

The data look like this:

```
head(health)
Country     Region    Population  LifeExpectancy HealthExpenditure
Albania     Europe      3204284      76.90095        2.202286
Algeria   Middle East  35468208      72.85254        1.981556
Angola     Africa      19081912      50.65366        1.461099
Argentina Latin America 40412376     75.63215        7.592994
Armenia    Europe       3092072      73.78356        1.337856
Australia  East Asia    22065300     81.69512       51.735024
```

I need to create a plotof life expectancy against health expenditure (in $100’s). The plot should consist of circles drawn
at (HealthExpenditure[i] LifeExpectancy[i]) with radius
sqrt(Population[i])/10000, and the fill colour of each circle should
indicate the region.

However, when I tried

```
circle(HealthExpenditure,LifeExpectancy,(sqrt(Population)/1000)),
```

the function doesn't work.
I also tried re-defining the function with the column names as default values without success.

How could I apply the function to the above column names and plot the circles of countries one by one? (I am trying to use the eqscplot function from MASS.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `mapply` to run an iteration element-wise across same length vectors (i.e., multiple apply). With this approach, you do not need to run a `for` loop inside of defined function. Below outputs using original *circle* version exactly as posted attempt, `circle(c(0,2), c(0,0), c(1, 0.5))`, on `for` loop version of *circle*:

```
circle <- function(x, y, r,...) {       
    ti <- seq(0, (2*pi), length.out = 100)           
    polygon(x + r *sin(ti), y+r*cos(ti),...)
}

df <- data.frame(x=c(0,2), y=c(0,0), z=c(1, 0.5))

plot(c(-3,3), c(-3,3), type="n")
mapply(circle, df$x, df$y, df$z)
```

For actual dataframe, similarly use `mapply`. And of course adjust plot dimensions and dataframe name, *df*, accordingly:

```
df <- read.table(text='Country     Region    Population  LifeExpectancy HealthExpenditure
Albania     Europe      3204284      76.90095        2.202286
Algeria   "Middle East"  35468208      72.85254        1.981556
Angola     Africa      19081912      50.65366        1.461099
Argentina "Latin America" 40412376     75.63215        7.592994
Armenia    Europe       3092072      73.78356        1.337856
Australia  "East Asia"    22065300     81.69512       51.735024', header=TRUE)

# COLOR FILL AND COLOR BORDER ADDED
circle <- function(x, y, r, c,...) {       
  ti <- seq(0, (2*pi), length.out = 100)           
  polygon(x + r *sin(ti), y+r*cos(ti),col=c,border=c,...)
}
# RANDOMLY SAMPLE FROM palette()
color_list <- sample(rep(palette(), nrow(df)), nrow(df), replace=TRUE)

plot(c(0,100), c(0,100), type="n")
output <- mapply(circle, df$HealthExpenditure, df$LifeExpectancy, (sqrt(df$Population)/1000), color_list)
```

[image: Circle Polygon Plot]

Comment: Thank you for your reply Parfait. I tried this solution, but unfortunately the command returns NULL for every row and it doesn't show anything on the plot. I still don't know what might be wrong.

Comment: See update using your posted data where I only adjust x and y coordinates of plot. I even add colors passing as another vector. You can assign `mapply` to an object like *output* to avoid print out of NULLs.